# Vacuum stats on read replica

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

We have a **hot_standby** replication configured for our postgresDB, master is for read/write and replica is a read only server.

When I try to fetch the dead tuple count on both master and replica (slave) using the following query

```
#########vacuum and analyze stats
SELECT relname,last_autovacuum,last_autoanalyze,autovacuum_count,autoanalyze_count FROM pg_stat_user_tables;
#########vacuum and analyze stats
```

I got the below data on slave server

```
MyTestDB=# SELECT relname,last_autovacuum,last_autoanalyze,autovacuum_count,autoanalyze_count FROM pg_stat_user_tables;
              relname              | last_autovacuum | last_autoanalyze | autovacuum_count | autoanalyze_count
-----------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------
Table1                             |                  |                  |                0 |                 0
Table2                             |                  |                  |                0 |                 0
```

Here the question is, does analyze/vacuum applicable for slave server? if so, it should contain some stats like last autovacuum_count, autoanalyze_count?

**Note:** As per this thread in [postgres forum](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CABUevEySGifJJh8c%2B4YDTyB%3Du-qUT7jA%2BYBgfgjEU_UAO2vGuw%40mail.gmail.com) VACUUM and ANALYZE are automatically replicated into slave

Answer (score 2):

`VACUUM` and `ANALYZE` won't run on standby servers (the results of these operations on the primary are replicated along with all other data), so you will never see statistics that show that they have run.

Comment: Thank you for your response, if possible can you please share a Postgres documentation link as a reference (I didn't find any related info in official documentation)

Comment: I don't think that is mentioned explicitly. But since both operations modify the database, they can of course not be run on a standby server. And all data modifications, including metadata modifications, are replicated.